# Windows 10; connected to the internet and an unidentified network

Tags: networking

I am confused and worried about why my desktop Windows 10 computer's network properties list,  it says that I am connected to the internet AND an Unidentified network.
The network properties list shows my ISP, lists my router, and then at the bottom of list of properties, it says I am connected to the internet and an unidentified network. I have some fears that my system may be compromised and I am suspicious that I may have a compromised home. 
I have McAfee Live safe and Windows Defender.
***Can anyone help me identify this unknown network and / or get rid of the unidentified network and help me secure my computer and home network.***

Comment: It could be your 'McAfee Live' , do you have a VPN?,

Comment: There's nothing inherently malicious about a network being "unidentified." That's Windows way of telling you it doesn't have enough information to classify it (as being Public, Private, Domain, etc.). Please [edit] your question to include the output of `ipconfig /all` as this will probably explain why Windows is showing multiple networks.

Comment: Where do I input or type this command? ipconfig/all

Answer (score 0):

If you have info in your connection settings seeing an unidentified network. It may be just that you have IPV6 enabled on your router and in Adapter settings.. BUT your ISP does not support IPV6 (e.g. Frontier Ca.) this will show a local link address under IPV6, but does not connect to the internet no packets can be sent. This causes the Unidentified Network info to appear in the settings window. It may (MAY) not have anything to do with "no connection to internet' problems.